# Resolving symlinks in Python without failing with missing components (like "readlink -m")

Tags: python

GNU `readlink` supports a command-line invocation similar to:

```
readlink -m /some/path/which/may/contain/symlinks
```

...which takes a path as an argument, and returns a path that *does not* contain any symlinks as a result (insofar as it is possible to do this), by replacing those link elements with the "real"/absolute paths they refer to. *Unlike `readlink -f` or `readlink -e`, this tolerates (proceeds without failure) when any path element does not exist.*

Is any equivalent operation available in Python?

Comment: I've tried to edit this to make the desired operation more clear and specific, even to people not familiar with GNU coreutils. If someone who might be inclined to cast a further close vote would be so kind as to describe the question's remaining deficiencies so as to allow them to be addressed, this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`os.path.realpath()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) does this.

```
$ rm -rf -- /tmp/nonexisting.XYZ     # just to be extra clear
$ orig_path=/tmp/nonexisting.XYZ/foo # on MacOS, where /tmp is at /private/tmp
$ greadlink -m "$orig_path"          # demonstrate GNU readlink output for comparison...
/private/tmp/nonexisting.XYZ/foo
$ python -c 'import os.path, sys; print(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[1]))' "$orig_path"
/private/tmp/nonexisting.XYZ/foo
```